# How to add a device with VID/PID in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, smartcard, pcsc

I am working on a smartcard project in Linux, and I am using Alcor 9563 smartcard reader, I use ccid/pcsc , but Linux doesn't identify the reader:

[image]

How can I add this device with vid/pid in Linux?

Comment: After you plugin this device, what does `dmesg` say ? It should show the device id/name!

Comment: it says : [ 5671.508303] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 5680.650474] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 5680.811374] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2ce3, idProduct=9563
[ 5680.811381] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 5680.811385] usb 1-1: Product: EMV Smartcard Reader
[ 5680.811390] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Generic

Comment: I don't see this reader on this list: https://wiki.debian.org/Smartcards Try this: https://community.linuxmint.com/hardware/view/24233 (EMV Smartcard Reader)

Comment: hi @gorlok , I tried but couldn't do again. Thank you for support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ccid.apdu.fr/ is the homepage of libccid. It has a list of supported readers. I didn't find your reader. It also has detailed instruction how to test if a reader is supported and how to contact the developers.

The Vendor ID looks interesting, it is not the one usually used by Alcor, and it is not known to the USB ID repository https://usb-ids.gowdy.us/read/UD?restrict=2

**Update** The Reader is now supported in libccid since version 1.4.31
https://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.com/2019/08/new-version-of-libccid-1431.html

Comment: hi @arved , thank you for support, my manager shelved this project for now

Comment: the same 2ce3:9563 smartcard reader is used in new Lenovo ThinkPad P16, year 2022